# Error: definition conflict with previous value

Tags: ios, swift

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("nameCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    let pancakeHouse = pancakeHouses[indexPath.row]
    if let cell = cell as? FAQsViewCell {
        cell.pancakeHouse = pancakeHouse
    } else {
        cell.textLabel?.text = pancakeHouse.que
    }


    return cell
}
```

I got error in this function of UITableViewController when I run my project at that time I got it I can't understand why it came or what is its meaning.

Comment: Which line does the error appear on?

Comment: Can you please provide more info ?

Comment: now it solved thanku

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "definition conflicts with previous value" occurred also when you forgot to set the **Cell Identifier**

Make sure you have set the correct identifier to your custom cell (in your case "nameCell") :

[image]

Comment: thanku so much i added identifier but i thought it not saved well that's why i got that erroe now it solved