# Parsing four comma separated values from a single string with Swift

Tags: string, parsing, swift5

I need to parse four comma-separated values of Double type from a single string (e.g. "0.0100, 2.0200, 0.10, 0.000"). The string length is unknown, has no specific terminator, and contains values with a different number of characters. This would be so simple in C but not being exactly fluent in Swift, is causing me a great deal of discomfort.
Is there an elegant way to do this in Swift? If so, please give an example.

Comment: `.components(separatedBy: ", ")`?

Comment: First https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678373/split-a-string-into-an-array-in-swift, then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51507121/convert-array-of-string-into-double-in-swift . It's all one line of code when done.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Sweeper and rmaddy, it's just one line of code, you can do it like this:

```
let commaSeparatedString = "0.0100, 2.0200, 0.10, 0.000"
let doubleValuesArray = commaSeparatedString.components(separatedBy: ", ").map { Double($0) } // [Optional(0.01), Optional(2.02), Optional(0.1), Optional(0.0)]
```

They are optionals because mapping a string to double may fail. If you want your `doubleValuesArray` to only contain non-optional values, you can use `compactMap` instead of `map`. Like this:

```
let doubleValuesArray = commaSeparatedString.components(separatedBy: ", ").compactMap { Double($0) } // [0.01, 2.02, 0.1, 0.0]
```

Comment: Wow! I had no idea there would be something as simple and powerful as commaSeparatedString.components(). Where can I find API documentation for powerful methods/functions like this?